# Export selected all rows from JSP to Excel

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JSP page that shows data from the database using jscript (I think). First column is the Checkbox. In the header, I have the 1st item as CheckboxAll. When I select this one, it selects all rows and it shows the total number of rows.

But due to Display tag and pagination, I see 10 rows on each page. So if I have 13 rows total, I see 10 on the first page and 3 on the second page. I am trying to export all selected 13 rows by pressing the *Export* button at the bottom outside of the Display tag. I see it is carrying only the 10 visible rows, not all 13. So at any time, it only exports the selected rows from the current page. How can I export all rows?

Display tag is working perfectly when I need to select from the viewed page and export the selected list without hard work. But I need to export all rows too. How can I export all rows, by selecting them all, to an Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
export.pdf.class=org.displaytag.export.PdfView
```

or

```
export.pdf.class=org.displaytag.export.DefaultPdfExportView
```